# Error by webview

Tags: android, search, webview

I have an search box with under the search box an webview.
when i type in the search box "hello", the webview show the html file "hello.html"
But when i change ("file:///android_asset/"+srt) to ("file:///android_asset/main/"+srt)
The webview says that the file main/hello.html can't find.

my full code is this:

```
package com.kerk.liedboek;

 import com.kerk.liedboek.R;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle; 
 import android.view.KeyEvent;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.Window;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
 import android.webkit.WebView;
 import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.TextView;



 public class psalmen extends Activity {
 WebView webview;
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     final Activity activity = this;
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);
         webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
         webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            String str = edit.getText().toString() +".html";
            webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/main/"+str);            }
    });
}  


 }
```

What am i doing wrong?

when i have ("file:///android_asset/"+str) it works fine but with the other one not.
I hope you understand me and that you can help me.

Gromdroid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have subfolders in any of the Android resource folders.

[Res Help 1](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html)

[Res Help 2](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html)

but it looks like your trying to load a html file. Put it in your raw folder:

```
/res/raw/home.html
```

then use:

```
file:///android_asset/raw/home.html
```